# Excel SQL External Data Return All Results If Parameter Is Empty

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, excel-external-data

Good Morning,

I am connecting to an external data source in Excel using SQL to retreive the records.
Returning the data is fine when I specify a value for the paramter I have defined.

What I am wanting to achieve is if the parameter (linked to a cell) is blank/empty then to return all records.

I'm not too sure how to state this but the paramter is in the WHERE clause of the SQL
e.g. `WHERE (Specialty.SpecialtyCODE = ?)`

Regards
Dino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I patch fixed this by linking to another cell which is linked to my parameter.

```
   =IF(CELL1="",1,CELL1)
```

My Specialty codes are all in the 100's so I was ok to specifiy 1 for my filter.
Then I applied this to my WHERE clause

```
WHERE  (Specialty.SpecialtyCODE LIKE
    CASE WHEN ? = 1 THEN
        %
    ELSE
        ?
    END)
```

This worked fine and returned what I expected.
Hopefully someone will find this useful or otherwise someone else could show another way around this.